# Samba can not parse path when connect Time machine

Tags: linux, macos, samba, time-machine, tomato

I used freshtomato on Netgear R7000, and I wanted to make it as a time machine, so i installed `Samba` and `Avahi`, so I can find my hard drive in system preferences of macOS. But, mac keept asking me the name and password of my server. So I checked the log of freshtomato. And I found the log:

```
Jul 5 13:47:57  daemon  err smbd[31405] parse_dfs_path_strict: Hostname findyy._smb._tcp.local is not ours. 
Jul 5 13:47:57  daemon  err smbd[31405] parse_dfs_path_strict: Hostname findyy._smb._tcp.local is not ours.
Jul 5 13:47:57  daemon  err smbd[31405] parse_dfs_path_strict: can't parse hostname from path \findyy._smb._tcp.local
```

And this is my config of samba:

```
[global]
 log file = /var/log/samba/log.%m
 interfaces = br0
 hosts allow = 10.0.0.25
 remote announce = findyy.local
 bind interfaces only = yes
 enable core files = no
 deadtime = 30
 smb encrypt = disabled
 min receivefile size = 16384
 workgroup = WORKGROUP
 netbios name = findyy
 server string = FreshTomato Samba Server
 dos charset = ASCII
 unix charset = UTF8
 guest account = nobody
 security = user

 guest ok = no
 guest only = no
 browseable = yes
 timestamp logs = no
 passdb backend = smbpasswd
 preserve case = yes
 short preserve case = yes
 load printers = no
 printing = bsd
 printcap name = /dev/null
 map archive = no
 map hidden = no
 map read only = no
 map system = no
 store dos attributes = no
 dos filemode = yes                      
 strict locking = no                     
 oplocks = yes                           
 level2 oplocks = yes                    
 kernel oplocks = no       
 use sendfile = yes        
 wins support = no         
 max protocol = SMB2       
 domain master = yes       
 local master = yes        
 preferred master = yes    
 os level = 255            
 socket options = TCP_NODELAY SO_KEEPALIVE IPTOS_LOWDELAY SO_RCVBUF=65536 SO_SNDBUF=65536
                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                          
[Time_Machine]                                                                           
 path = /tmp/mnt/Time_Machine                                                            
 comment = Time_Machine                                                                  
 writable = yes                                                                          
 delete readonly = yes                                                                   
 force user = root,findyy                                                                
 vfs objects = catia fruit streams_xattr                                                 
 fruit:time machine = yes
```

This is my config of `Avahi`:

```
[server]
host-name=findyy
domain-name=.alocal
use-ipv4=yes
use-ipv6=yes
check-response-ttl=no
use-iff-running=no
#enable-dbus=0

[publish]
publish-addresses=yes
publish-hinfo=yes
publish-workstation=no
publish-domain=yes
                                   
[reflector]                        
enable-reflector=no
reflect-ipv=no     
                   
[rlimits]     
#rlimit-as=
rlimit-core=0
rlimit-data=4194304
rlimit-fsize=0     
rlimit-nofile=30   
rlimit-stack=4194304
rlimit-nproc=3
```

And this is the config of `Avahi` services:

```
<?xml version="1.0" standalone='no'?><!--*-nxml-*-->
<!DOCTYPE service-group SYSTEM "avahi-service.dtd">
<service-group>
  <name replace-wildcards="yes">%h</name>
  <service>
    <type>_smb._tcp</type>
    <port>445</port>
  </service>
  <service>
    <type>_device-info._tcp</type>
    <port>9</port>
    <txt-record>model=TimeCapsule8,119</txt-record>
  </service>
  <service>
    <type>_adisk._tcp</type>
    <port>9</port>
    <txt-record>dk0=adVN=Time_Machine,adVF=0x82</txt-record>
    <txt-record>sys=adVF=0x100</txt-record>
  </service>
</service-group>
```

Comment: May be a red herring, but you've go a spurious "a" in "domain-name=.alocal". It should be just ".local".

Answer (score 0):

The issue seems to be a problem with a samba configuration which causes the following error to occur.

parse_dfs_path_strict: can't parse hostname from path

The source of the issue appears to be a misconfiguration of the smb.conf. smb.conf allows for forcing a user and group for a share. If the user or group does not exist on the host or incorrect permissions, that issue will occur on connection. Changing it to valid user with the correct permissions for the share seems to fix the issue.

```
[share]
force group = "username"
force user = "username"
path = /path
valid users = "username"
```